# PendingIntent sticks around after notification is dismissed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I wrote the following method to check if a notification is active (visible on the status bar):

```
public static boolean isNotificationActive(Context context, int id) {
  Intent intentPopup = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
  PendingIntent test = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intentPopup, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
  return test != null;
}
```

I create a PendingIntent exactly like the one I want to be checked (the same 'intentPopup' and 'id' are passed to this PendingIntent) and, because of FLAG_NO_CREATE, I expect this PendingIntent to be null if it doesn't exist yet. I read about this method in a thread posted years ago here.

If the notification has not yet been issued, the method returns the expected value (false). When the notification is issued and is in the status bar, the method returns true.

However, after I dismiss the notification, the method still returns true, as if the PendingIntent is still there.

What am I missing here? Is the PendingIntent still available or am I misunderstanding something?

Is there a better way to check if a specific notification is active (being displayed in the status bar)?

EDIT: here's the code that creates the notification:

```
    Intent intentPopup = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
            intentPopup.putExtra("id", id);
            intentPopup.putExtra("timeQ", timeQ);

    PendingIntent pendingIntentPopup = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intentPopup, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntentPopup)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.q_notification_icon)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification_sound"))
                    .setVibrate(vibrate_pattern);

            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: Post the code you use to create the `Notification`

Comment: @DavidWasser Posted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `PendingIntent`s that you embed in a `Notification` do not automatically disappear when the `Notification` is dismissed, viewed, or canceled. You can't use the presence or absence of a `PendingIntent` (using `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` like you've done) to determine whether or not a `Notification` is active.

To determine if a `Notification` is active, you can call `NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()`. This will return all active `Notification`s that your app has posted.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, getActiveNotifications() was introduced in API 23 and my app's minsdk is 19... Thanks anyway, @DavidWasser. I'll keep looking for an alternative.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `NotificationListenerService`. This was introduced in API 18, so you can use it. It is a bit more complicated but should give you what you want. There is a method `getActiveNotifications()`.